# Is it possible to create a hls master playlist with .ts chunks?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to create a hls master playlist with .ts chunks(of different playlists) instead of creating it with different variants playlist in nginx using ffmpeg, Can one do that?  if not is there any way I can immediately create the master playlist as soon as nginx receives the first .ts chunk?

Thanks, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: A master playlist must point to a variant playlist. Are you asking if you can skip that step? If so, the answer is no. If you are asking if you can create a variant playlist from a ts chunk, the create a master playlist for the variant playlist, then yes.